# How can I get data from an action?

Tags: redux-saga

For example there is an Action:

```
export const loginSuccessAction = (user: UserInterface) => {
  return (dispatch: Dispatch<ActionInterface>) => {
    dispatch({ type: ActionTypes.LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: user });
  };
};
```

It is possible being in Watcher to get (user: UserInterface) from loginSuccessAction?

Thank You very much for Your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, each of the methods for taking an action will give you the action object, and since you've put the user on the payload property, you can use that. For example with `takeEvery`:

```
function* watchLogin() {
   yield takeEvery(ActionTypes.LOGIN_SUCCESS, loginSuccessSaga);
}

function* loginSuccessSaga(action) {
  console.log('user: ', action.payload);
}
```

Or with `take`:

```
function* someSaga() {
  const action = yield take(ActionTypes.LOGIN_SUCCESS);
  console.log('user: ', action.payload);
}
```